# Undefined offset: 5 in /home/myiptvitalia/public_html/wp-content/themes/whmcssmarters-iptv7/includes/builder/functions.php on line 1749

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently I change my server and see some error in one of my website page . its show

> Undefined offset: 5 in /home/myiptvitalia/public_html/wp-content/themes/whmcssmarters-iptv7/includes/builder/functions.php on line 1749

How can I solve this ?

```
foreach ( $values as $element_style_value ) {
            if ( '' !== $element_style_value ) {
                $element_style .= sprintf(
                    '%3$s-%1$s: %2$s%4$s; ',
    esc_attr( $positions[ $i ] ), //    **this is the line 1749--**
                    esc_attr( et_builder_process_range_value( $element_style_value, $property ) ),
                    esc_attr( $property ),
                    ( $use_important ? ' !important' : '' )
                );
            }

            $i++;
        }

        $style .= rtrim( $element_style );
    }

    return $style;
}
endif;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    foreach ( $values as $element_style_value ) {
        if ( '' !== $element_style_value ) {
            $element_style .= sprintf(
                '%3$s-%1$s: %2$s%4$s; ',
                esc_attr( $positions[ $i ] ),
                esc_attr( et_builder_process_range_value( $element_style_value, $property ) ),
                esc_attr( $property ),
                ( $use_important ? ' !important' : '' )
            );
        }

        $i++;
    }

    $style .= rtrim( $element_style );
}

return $style;
```

}
endif;

Comment: If you are going to answer any question (even your own) you should put some explanation of how this has fixed the problem.